# "ERROR: Unable to find a version of the runtime to use" running Exe from Network share

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple .Net 2.0 application which is to run from a network share. It works normally on most client machines but gets an error ""ERROR: Unable to find a version of the runtime to use" on one machine. The drive is mapped (M:\myexe.exe) but the problem is the same from the UNC path.

The machine is running Windows 7 x64 (and therefore has .Net 3.5 SP1 which should allow managed code run from a network share). I have tried:

- Disabling .Net 3.5.1 and Re-enabling
- Repairing using .Net Framework repair tool http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135
- Setting Exe to x86, x64 and 'Any CPU'
- Logging CLR issues using reg 'hack' as outlined here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152929(v=vs.110).aspx
- Rebooting
- I didn't have a config file but when I added one specifying supportedRuntime I got a slightly different error - "this application has stopped working"

Other points of interest:
- My exe runs fine from the local machine itself (c:\temp\myexe.exe)
- I created a sub-directory on the network drive (M:\New) and copied my exe there and it works without problems (M:\New\MyExe.exe)
- On the M drive (where it doesn't work), there used to be a non .Net exe of the same name. I thought there might be some weird (prefetch) caching going on.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. The only fix is copying in a subfolder...